# How to sideload videos from a server into YouTube

Tags: youtube, download, upload

There is a big video file, hosted on a web server and I have a slow internet connection. Instead of downloading and uploading it, I wish to directly SIDELOAD it into YouTube.

Is there a web app which works as an API interface?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not support FTP upload of videos. You will need to solve it using some 3rd-party tools, for example, **[Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/en/integration/41-automatically-upload-new-videos-from-ftp-to-youtube-and-update-your-twitter-status)**.